# Wordpress get_category or get_post

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know how to explain my problem but I like to echo the specific category/ slug inside the specified section (sorting off by categories). I don't know which Wordpress function should be use? is it get_category or get_post?
so far I have this code to echo all the categories in one section:

```
         <?php
         $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'allproducts',
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
         );
            $posts = get_posts( $args );
            foreach ( $posts as $post ):
            setup_postdata( $post );
        ?>
```

basically my goal is to get all the post from specific category:
I have these list of categories with specific slugs and ID:

```
Category Name | Slug | ID
Shoes         | cat01|  2
Pants         | cat02|  3
Tops          | cat03|  4
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. here's my code:

```
        <?php 
            $args1 = array( 'posts_per_page' => 9, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => array(1));
            $myposts1 = get_posts( $args1 );
        
            foreach ( $myposts1 as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
        ?>
```

array (1) --> is the id of my category

closed it with this code

```
                <?php endforeach; 
                wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
) );

foreach($categories as $category)
{
  $cateid = $category->term_id;
  $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'allproducts',
        'category' => $cateid,
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
     );
  $posts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach ( $posts as $post ){
// here rest of code of posts.
  }      
}
```